# Why this powershell command produces no output?

Tags: powershell

Let's consider a.ps1:

```
[pscustomobject]@{date=(Get-Date);id="test"}
exit 0
```

And the following two commands that execute it:

Command 1: `powershell -noprofile -ex unrestricted "& './a.ps1'; exit $lastexitcode"` - no output.

Command 2: `powershell -noprofile -ex unrestricted "& './a.ps1';  $lastexitcode"`, output:

```
date               id
----               --
07-May-19 11:04:54 test
0
```

Can you explain why the first command produces no output? I would expect it to print out the same object with `date` and `id` that the second command prints out (but obviously, not the exit code).

Note: I tested this with powershell 5 and powershell 6 from both cmd.exe and powershell console. In all cases results were the same.

Comment: `write-output [pscustomobject]@{date=(Get-Date);id="test"}` works, seems powershell handle the psobject and string object in a different way between calling and not calling `exit`.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that's due to the intrinsic delay in output processing that PS enforces.

All output is delayed by about 300ms in order for it to properly figure out column widths for variable-width items in display formatting when rendering output. For example, in `Get-ChildItem` output it is necessary for you to be able to get the nice useful tabular formatting without having the headers appear every single line

If you call `exit` too soon after output, the output won't get displayed because the output pipeline that the results have to travel through will be deconstructed before the data gets there. To bypass this, have the results piped to `Out-String | Write-Host` or just `Out-Host` before calling `exit` to force the results to reach the host before the subprocess is actually exited.

Links illustrating / explaining portions of this:

- https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/write-output-or-write-host-powershell
- https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/14925213-bug-console-output-appears-out-of-order (check last answer for comprehensive details)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/b43uzq/help_with_some_odd_behavior_in_powershell/ej6295y?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

I'd thought there was a builtin help topic for this, but I didn't see it from a cursory glance of `about_*` topics...

Comment: `If you call exit too soon after output, the output won't get displayed because` If I add `sleep 10` between the script and `exit` there is still no output, although in this case exit should not be called too soon. I think there might be something else going here. Also if you remove `[pscustomobject]` it also starts working even with the `exit`.

Comment: Nope. `Start-Sleep` (aliased to `sleep` by default) sleeps the _entire thread_. PowerShell doesn't do a lot in terms of multithreading, so if you call that command, the output processing _also_ halts.

I'd have to do some testing, but from what I recall the formatting for hashtables is far simpler than that used for custom objects, so there's a better chance for it to be processed before the process executes the `exit` command.

Comment: Delay is used to decide on column width, not to group objects. `Get-ChildItem` for `FileSystem` provider use formatting with fixed column width, so it is not delayed.

Comment: @JoelFrancis, well you can run a tight loop instead of sleep with the same result. Surely a tight loop does not pause the thread, as interpreter keeps executing command, pipeline is running, etc. `"[pscustomobject]@{date=(Get-Date);id='test'};\`$till = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(10); while((Get-Date) -lt \`$till) { \`$с++ } ;exit 0"`

Comment: [This](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/2be3db8ab8757fe9ecccd2cc545ae9044ed76574/src/System.Management.Automation/FormatAndOutput/common/BaseOutputtingCommand.cs#L158) is the 300ms you seem to be referring to.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh *Surely a tight loop does not pause the thread, as interpreter keeps executing command, pipeline is running, etc.* It does not matter how you consume the thread: by sleeping or by tight loop. What matter is that you are exclusively consuming thread and not give it to formatting system, so that it can anticipate that 300ms interval has passed. `[pscustomobject]@{ date = (Get-Date); id = 'test' }; sleep 1; 'Hello formatting system'; exit 0`